# How to merge dataframes based on unique functional keys while keeping one table as truth for select columns on merged duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation

Advanced Python Pandas question here

EX:

Suppose I have two data frames

Dataframe #1

| Date | Time | Name | location | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/11 | 11:59 PM | James | LAX | a | b |
| 02/12 | 02:00 PM | Harry | IAD | c | d |
| 02/12 | 05:00 PM | Harry | IAD | e | f |
| 02/11 | 12:00 AM | John | LAX | h | i |
| 02/12 | 05:30 AM | John | IAD | g | k |

Dataframe #2

| Date | Time | Name | location | A_1 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/12 | 12:30 AM | James | LAX | l | m |
| 02/12 | 02:00 PM | Harry | IAD | n | o |
| 02/12 | 05:00 PM | Harry | IAD | k | l |
| 02/11 | 1:01 AM | John | LAX | p | q |
| 02/13 | 05:30 AM | John | IAD | r | s |
| 02/12 | 05:30 AM | Ender | DAL | t | u |

Combined data frame

| Date | Time | Name | Location | A | B | A_1 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/11 | 11:59 PM | James | LAX | a | b | l | m |
| 02/12 | 02:00 PM | Harry | IAD | c | d | n | o |
| 02/12 | 05:00 PM | Harry | IAD | e | f | k | l |
| 02/11 | 12:00 AM | John | LAX | h | i | n/a | n/a |
| 02/12 | 05:30 AM | John | IAD | g | k | n/a | n/a |
| 02/11 | 1:01 AM | John | LAX | n/a | n/a | p | q |
| 02/13 | 05:30 AM | John | IAD | n/a | n/a | r | s |
| 02/12 | 05:30 AM | Ender | DAL | n/a | n/a | t | u |

How could Dataframe #1 and Dataframe #2 be merged to produce the combined data frame

Here are the rules that need to be satisfied

1. I would like the merge to be "on" 3 attributes: columns "Name" and "Location" must be an exact match and the date/time difference must be equal to or within an hour (ex: "02/11  11:59 PM  James  LAX" and "02/12  12:30 AM  James  LAX" would match but "02/11  12:00 AM  John  LAX" and "02/11  1:01 AM  John  LAX" would not match and create a second entry in the combined df)
2. I would like the data from columns A, B, A_1, and B_2 to be added to the combined table
3. Data Frame #1 is to be the source of truth so when the time is within an hour but different, data frames 1 time is what is used in the combined data frame
4. Outer join so all data is kept

I have tried all the basic merge parameters, which has not helped merge the tables with the hour time constraint. I tried creating a temporary column with combined date and time +1 and -1 hour but could not figure out how to incorporate this into the merge keys.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a  [`.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) problem.

- `direction = "nearest"` to get the nearest matches.
- `tolerance = pd.Timedelta("1h")` to "limit" the match to within 1 hour.

```
# convert to datetimes
df1["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"] + " " + df1["Time"], format="%m/%d %H:%M %p")
df2["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"] + " " + df2["Time"], format="%m/%d %H:%M %p")

# 'on' must be sorted in both dataframes
# 'by' is used group by
near = pd.merge_asof(
   df1.sort_values("dt"),
   df2.assign(dt_y=df2["dt"]).sort_values("dt"),
   by=["Name", "location"],
   on="dt",
   direction="nearest",
   tolerance=pd.Timedelta("1h"),
   suffixes=("", "_y"),
)

# Find rows from `df2` that did not match
far = near[["Name", "location", "dt_y"]].dropna().merge(df2, how="outer", indicator=True)
```

```
>>> near
    Date      Time   Name location  A  B                  dt Date_y    Time_y  A_1  B_2                dt_y
0  02/11  11:59 PM  James      LAX  a  b 1900-02-11 11:59:00    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
1  02/11  12:00 AM   John      LAX  h  i 1900-02-11 12:00:00    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
2  02/12  02:00 PM  Harry      IAD  c  d 1900-02-12 02:00:00  02/12  02:00 PM    n    o 1900-02-12 02:00:00
3  02/12  05:00 PM  Harry      IAD  e  f 1900-02-12 05:00:00  02/12  05:00 PM    k    l 1900-02-12 05:00:00
4  02/12  05:30 AM   John      IAD  g  k 1900-02-12 05:30:00    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
```

`right_only` rows are rows that did not have a near match.

```
>>> far
    Name location                dt_y   Date      Time A_1 B_2                  dt      _merge
0  Harry      IAD 1900-02-12 02:00:00  02/12  02:00 PM   n   o 1900-02-12 02:00:00        both
1  Harry      IAD 1900-02-12 02:00:00  02/12  05:00 PM   k   l 1900-02-12 05:00:00        both
2  Harry      IAD 1900-02-12 05:00:00  02/12  02:00 PM   n   o 1900-02-12 02:00:00        both
3  Harry      IAD 1900-02-12 05:00:00  02/12  05:00 PM   k   l 1900-02-12 05:00:00        both
4  James      LAX                 NaT  02/12  12:30 AM   l   m 1900-02-12 12:30:00  right_only
5   John      LAX                 NaT  02/11   1:01 AM   p   q 1900-02-11 01:01:00  right_only
6   John      IAD                 NaT  02/13  05:30 AM   r   s 1900-02-13 05:30:00  right_only
7  Ender      DAL                 NaT  02/12  05:30 AM   t   u 1900-02-12 05:30:00  right_only
```

You can then combine `near` and the `right_only` rows from `far`

```
pd.concat([
   near,
   far.loc[far["_merge"] == "right_only"]
]).drop(columns=["dt", "_merge"])
```

```
    Date      Time   Name location    A    B Date_y    Time_y  A_1  B_2                dt_y
0  02/11  11:59 PM  James      LAX    a    b    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
1  02/11  12:00 AM   John      LAX    h    i    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
2  02/12  02:00 PM  Harry      IAD    c    d  02/12  02:00 PM    n    o 1900-02-12 02:00:00
3  02/12  05:00 PM  Harry      IAD    e    f  02/12  05:00 PM    k    l 1900-02-12 05:00:00
4  02/12  05:30 AM   John      IAD    g    k    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN                 NaT
4  02/12  12:30 AM  James      LAX  NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    l    m                 NaT
5  02/11   1:01 AM   John      LAX  NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    p    q                 NaT
6  02/13  05:30 AM   John      IAD  NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    r    s                 NaT
7  02/12  05:30 AM  Ender      DAL  NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    t    u                 NaT
```

---

#### duckdb

You may also be interested in [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html) which allows you to run sql queries against dataframes.

```
duckdb.query("""
from 
   (select *, strptime(date || ' ' || time, '%m/%d %H:%M %p') as dt from df1) t1
   full join 
   (select *, strptime(date || ' ' || time, '%m/%d %H:%M %p') as dt from df2) t2
on 
   t1.name = t2.name
   and 
   t1.location = t2.location
   and
   t1.dt between (t2.dt - '1h'::interval) and (t2.dt + '1h'::interval)
select 
   coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date,
   coalesce(t1.time, t2.time) as time,
   coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
   coalesce(t1.location, t2.location) as location,
   A,
   B,
   A_1,
   B_2
""").df()
```

```
    date      time   name location    A    B  A_1  B_2
0  02/11  11:59 PM  James      LAX    a    b    l    m
1  02/12  05:00 PM  Harry      IAD    e    f    k    l
2  02/12  02:00 PM  Harry      IAD    c    d    n    o
3  02/11  12:00 AM   John      LAX    h    i  NaN  NaN
4  02/12  05:30 AM   John      IAD    g    k  NaN  NaN
5  02/11   1:01 AM   John      LAX  NaN  NaN    p    q
6  02/13  05:30 AM   John      IAD  NaN  NaN    r    s
7  02/12  05:30 AM  Ender      DAL  NaN  NaN    t    u
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated answer, see below for old answer

You can use `np.piecewise()` to perform a merge with multiple conditions that are not covered by standard `pd.merge()` options. Let us walk through it bit by bit.

First, we create the dataframes. For future reference, please provide this in this format yourself in future questions. It takes up time on our side, and that's just inefficient.

Note that I made a slight change to your dataframe: I created 1 date column (`dt`) rather than have that split in two columns. The scope of this answer is not on how to get from two to one column with date times, so I just incorporated it into the creation of the df's.

```
from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'dt': [Timestamp('2022-02-11 23:59:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 14:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 17:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-11 00:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 05:30:00')],
        'name': ['James', 'Harry', 'Harry', 'John', 'John'],
        'location': ['LAX','IAD', 'IAD','LAX', 'IAD'],
        'a': ['a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'g'],
        'b': ['b','d', 'f', 'i', 'k']
    }
)
#                    dt   name location  a  b
# 0 2022-02-11 23:59:00  James      LAX  a  b
# 1 2022-02-12 14:00:00  Harry      IAD  c  d
# 2 2022-02-12 17:00:00  Harry      IAD  e  f
# 3 2022-02-11 00:00:00   John      LAX  h  i
# 4 2022-02-12 05:30:00   John      IAD  g  k

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'dt': [Timestamp('2022-02-12 00:30:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 14:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 17:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-11 01:01:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-13 05:30:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 05:30:00')],
        'name': ['James', 'Harry', 'Harry', 'John', 'John', 'Ender'],
        'location': ['LAX','IAD', 'IAD','LAX', 'IAD', 'DAL'],
        'a_2': ['l', 'n', 'k', 'p', 'r', 't'],
        'b_2': ['m', 'o', 'l', 'q', 's','u']
    }
)
#                    dt   name location a_2 b_2
# 0 2022-02-12 00:30:00  James      LAX   l   m
# 1 2022-02-12 14:00:00  Harry      IAD   n   o
# 2 2022-02-12 17:00:00  Harry      IAD   k   l
# 3 2022-02-11 01:01:00   John      LAX   p   q
# 4 2022-02-13 05:30:00   John      IAD   r   s
# 5 2022-02-12 05:30:00  Ender      DAL   t   u
```

The second thing we will do, is add an `id` column to the second dataframe. That gives us unique pointers to the right records and will help with the merge later on:

```
df2['id'] = df2.index+1
```

Next, for clarity, we add two columns with the maximum deviation of the date time during our merg. We call these columns `mindt` and `maxdt`:

```
df2['mindt'] = df2['dt'] - Timedelta(1, unit='hour')
df2['maxdt'] = df2['dt'] + Timedelta(1, unit='hour')
```

Next up is the cool part! `np.piecewise` allows you to have conditional matching in an array. How does that work? It takes an array, and two lists; one conditions list and one function list. The condition list is a list of boolean series the size of your dataframe (df1 in this case). The function list is actually no function at all but another array of the same size. It applies every boolean array on the input array and sets the values according to the function list. Sounds complicated? It does to me, so here is a little example:

```
x = np.piecewise(
    np.zeros(4), # 1
    [np.array([False,False,False,False]), np.array([False, True, True, True]), np.array([False,True,True,False])], # 2
    [10,100, 1000] # 3
)

x
# array([   0., 1000., 1000.,  100.])
```

The input array is `[0,0,0,0]` (`np.zeros(4)`). The condition list (list with boolean arrays) contains 3 arrays, with size 4 (just as the input). The function list just contains 3 return values. Walking through it, applying the first boolean array on the input array, and applying the first function keeps the input array as it is (the condition is `False` on all elements). The second condition array is `True` on the second, third and fourth index, and thus the second function is applied on the input array's second, third, and fourth index. The input array now looks like `[0, 100, 100, 100]`. Going to the last (third) boolean array in the condition list, which only has the second and third element as `True`, and thus the second and third element of the input array is set to the third function in the function list (1000). Now the input array looks like `[0, 1000, 1000, 100]`.

Why is this relevant? Because we can create an `id` column to our `df1`, with the corresponding `id` value from `df2`. We do it like this:

```
df1['id'] = np.piecewise(
    np.zeros(len(df1)),
    [list((df1.dt.values >= min_date)&(df1.dt.values <= max_date)&(df1.name==name)&(df1.location==location)) for min_date, max_date, name, location in zip(df2.mindt.values, df2.maxdt.values, df2.name.values, df2.location.values)],
    df2['id'].values
)
```

Note that we create a list of boolean lists based on the condition that you want. The first boolean list looks like `[True, False, False, False, False]`. It has the length of `df1` and only on the index where there is a match with df2, the `True` value is set. Then, the elements in input array (which starts as `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`) for which the boolean list is `True` are set to the first value of the `id` column of `df2`. The end result is added to `df1` as column `id`, and `df1` now looks like this:

```
                   dt   name location  a  b   id
0 2022-02-11 23:59:00  James      LAX  a  b  1.0
1 2022-02-12 14:00:00  Harry      IAD  c  d  2.0
2 2022-02-12 17:00:00  Harry      IAD  e  f  3.0
3 2022-02-11 00:00:00   John      LAX  h  i  0.0
4 2022-02-12 05:30:00   John      IAD  g  k  0.0
```

We now have a single column we can merge `df1` and `df2` on, but we need to do this in two steps. First we merge `left`, adding the columns `a_2` and `b_2` for the rows that we have in `df1`:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2.drop(['dt', 'mindt', 'maxdt'], axis=1), on=['id', 'name', 'location'], how='left')
```

Now, `df1` looks like this (and we are getting real close!)

```
                   dt   name location  a  b   id  a_2  b_2
0 2022-02-11 23:59:00  James      LAX  a  b  1.0    l    m
1 2022-02-12 14:00:00  Harry      IAD  c  d  2.0    n    o
2 2022-02-12 17:00:00  Harry      IAD  e  f  3.0    k    l
3 2022-02-11 00:00:00   John      LAX  h  i  0.0  NaN  NaN
4 2022-02-12 05:30:00   John      IAD  g  k  0.0  NaN  NaN
```

Lastly, we merge `df2` again, but only for the rows that are not yet matched (we filter `df2` on the `id`'s that are already in `df['id']`). We then do an outer join:

```
df1 = df1.merge(
    df2.drop(['mindt', 'maxdt'], axis=1)[~df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])],
    on=['id', 'name', 'location', 'dt', 'a_2', 'b_2'], how='outer')
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
                   dt   name location    a    b   id  a_2  b_2
0 2022-02-11 23:59:00  James      LAX    a    b  1.0    l    m
1 2022-02-12 14:00:00  Harry      IAD    c    d  2.0    n    o
2 2022-02-12 17:00:00  Harry      IAD    e    f  3.0    k    l
3 2022-02-11 00:00:00   John      LAX    h    i  0.0  NaN  NaN
4 2022-02-12 05:30:00   John      IAD    g    k  0.0  NaN  NaN
5 2022-02-11 01:01:00   John      LAX  NaN  NaN  4.0    p    q
6 2022-02-13 05:30:00   John      IAD  NaN  NaN  5.0    r    s
7 2022-02-12 05:30:00  Ender      DAL  NaN  NaN  6.0    t    u
```

Note that this approach can save a lot of memory. The previous approach would work on small datasets, but the cartesian product from both frames could result in an unwieldy dataframe. The approach above is not the fastest maybe, because of the `piecewise` functions nature: it applies a boolean array to an input array N times, where N is equal to the length of your `df2`.

#### OLD ANSWER

I am sure there is a simpler and more elegant way, but I reached your desired endstate like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'dt': [Timestamp('2022-02-11 23:59:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 14:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 17:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-11 00:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 05:30:00')],
        'name': ['James', 'Harry', 'Harry', 'John', 'John'],
        'location': ['LAX','IAD', 'IAD','LAX', 'IAD'],
        'a': ['a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'g'],
        'b': ['b','d', 'f', 'i', 'k']
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'dt': [Timestamp('2022-02-12 00:30:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 14:00:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-12 17:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-11 01:01:00'),
               Timestamp('2022-02-13 05:30:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-12 05:30:00')],
        'name': ['James', 'Harry', 'Harry', 'John', 'John', 'Ender'],
        'location': ['LAX','IAD', 'IAD','LAX', 'IAD', 'DAL'],
        'a_2': ['l', 'n', 'k', 'p', 'r', 't'],
        'b_2': ['m', 'o', 'l', 'q', 's','u']
    }
)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
df3 = df3[(df3['name_x'] == df3['name_y']) & (df3['location_x']==df3['location_y'])
          & (df3['dt_y'] >= (df3['dt_x']-Timedelta(1, unit='hour'))) & (df3['dt_y'] <= (df3['dt_x']+Timedelta(1, unit='hour')))
          ]
df3 = df3.drop(['name_y', 'location_y', 'dt_y'], axis=1)
df3 = df3.rename(columns={
    'dt_x':'dt',
    'name_x': 'name',
    'location_x': 'location'
})
df = df3.merge(df1, on=['dt', 'name', 'location', 'a', 'b'], how='outer' )
df = df.merge(df2, on=['name', 'location', 'a_2', 'b_2'], how='outer')
df['dt_x'] = df['dt_x'].fillna(df['dt_y'])
df = df.drop(['dt_y'], axis=1).rename(columns={'dt_x':'dt'})
df
```

results in:

```
dt  name    location    a   b   a_2 b_2
0   2022-02-11 23:59:00 James   LAX a   b   l   m
1   2022-02-12 14:00:00 Harry   IAD c   d   n   o
2   2022-02-12 17:00:00 Harry   IAD e   f   k   l
3   2022-02-11 00:00:00 John    LAX h   i   NaN NaN
4   2022-02-12 05:30:00 John    IAD g   k   NaN NaN
5   2022-02-11 01:01:00 John    LAX NaN NaN p   q
6   2022-02-13 05:30:00 John    IAD NaN NaN r   s
7   2022-02-12 05:30:00 Ender   DAL NaN NaN t   u
```